# How to create cubic bezier curve using control points?

Tags: bezier-curve

How can I create the cubic bezier curve to (6,2) using control points (2,3.8) and (3.8,2)?

What I have tried:

I considered all the points as the control points 
  P<sub>0</sub>=(2,3.8)
  P<sub>2</sub>=(6,2) 
  P<sub>1</sub>=(3.8,2)

Consider the below equation:
∑ p<sub>i</sub> B<sub>i,n</sub> (u)

where B is the basis function.

and

B<sub>i,n</sub>(u)=<sup>n</sup>C<sub>i</sub>u<sup>i</sup>(1-u)<sup>n-i</sup>

SO I derived the equation:

=P<sub>0</sub>B<sub>0,2</sub>(u)+P<sub>1</sub>B<sub>1,2</sub>(u)+P<sub>2</sub>B<sub>2,2</sub>(u)

But I am not able to get anything using this equation. ANy Help?

Edit:

if I consider only two control points i.e  P<sub>0</sub>=(2,3.8) and P<sub>1</sub>=(3.8,2)
  then what is the use of point (6,2) and how we determine how much curly the path is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cubic bezier curve starting from point $P_0$, ending at point $P_3$ with two control points $P_1$ and $P_2$ is represented by the following,

$$B(t) = P_0(1-t)^3 + 3(1-t)^2tP_1 + 3(1-t)t^2P_2 + t^3P_3, \ \ t \in [0,1]$$

In your question, $P_1, P_2, P_3$ are given but $P_0$ is not satisfied. May be it is $(0,0)$. Please check the source of the question.

Comment: this equation is when there are 4 control points is given? @expiTTplz0 but In my question there are not 4 control points.

Comment: Hey thanks @expiTTp1z0 , I got it. I have read wrong from the source. NeverMind thanks